# Visualizing last refresh date in power bi

Tags: data-visualization, powerbi, dax, m

Is it possible to add a card in power BI that shows the last time the underneath dataset has been updated?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a blank query and use the following M query to create a single-cell table:

```
let
    Source = #table(type table[Last Refresh=datetime], {{DateTime.LocalNow()}})
in
    Source
```

[image: query]

And then you can use the `Card` visual and drag in the column to show it. You can rename the field to remove the default aggregation. (It doesn't matter since there is only one row of data anyways)

[image: result]

The value will be recalculated each time the data is refreshed.

Comment: Hi @nelson-gomes-matias this help solving the issue after all? If so, you can [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/313506) to positively close the question.

Answer (score 4):

you can achieve this by adding a `calculated column` (Refresh data Column) in the model with the formula `=NOW()`

Then add `measure`

```
Last Refresh Date :=MAX(Table[Last Refresh Column])
```

Since calculated columns are calculated only on model refresh - it will make sure the calculation is right.

Comment: That is slick!!

Answer (score 0):

The below code is working for me (for HK).
Add a column with the below formula

```
Last Refresh = FORMAT(UTCNOW()+TIME(8,0,0),"dd MMMM YYYY ttttt")
```

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the location it's really confusing with all those functions..
Let me suggest you the workable one:
Go to the:

Query Editor
1.right click on the Queries body on the left side
2.new queries
3.Blank Queries
4.Paste the following formula by putting the right Server Instances and DB Name,
" = Sql.Database("Server\Instance", "Database", [Query="select GETDATE() LastRefreshDate from AnyTableName"])

It'll work out. And since it's pulling directly from the server,, you don't have to worry about choosing the right DateTimeZone functions in PowerBI.