# Show LAST REFRESH timestamp in a PUBLISHED report on POWERBI SERVICE

Tags: datetime, powerbi, utc, powerbi-datasource

I already checked Stackoverflow for an answer, but I only found question related to showing a timestamp in **PowerBI Desktop**, which is pretty different from the behaviour in the **PowerBI Service**, e.g. see

[How to display current date and time in power bi visuals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55672251/how-to-display-current-date-and-time-in-power-bi-visuals)

[Visualizing last refresh date in power bi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46236102/visualizing-last-refresh-date-in-power-bi)

Why?

1. I don't want to see in my report the timestamp of the **current date
   and time**, since I already have this in the status bar of my
   operating system.
2. I don't want to see in my report the timestamp of
       the **last "report" refresh**, when only the measures get updated (like
       in the Service).
3. I don't want to see the **timestamp of last re-import**
       of (most-likely unchanged) data in the Desktop/Service.

What I want to see in my report is the **timestamp of the last "dataset" refresh** in the Service, which cannot be achived by a measure, but a M-function only!

The problem now is that the Service runs in **UTC time**, while I'm of cause interested in **local time**, and all the M-functions to convert a datetimezone number only only accept a fixed time-shift in hours, but do not consider daylight savings.

How would a solution look like to properly overcome this deficit and to show the **proper local time of the dataset refresh** in a PBI Service report?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround I've been pulling the proper local time from worldtimeapi.org so far, see e.g. this PowerQuery M-script:

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(
        Web.Contents("http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/Berlin")),
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(Source),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(
        #"Converted to Table", each ([Name] = "datetime")),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Name"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(
        #"Removed Columns",{{"Value", type datetimezone}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(
        #"Changed Type",{{"Value", "Europe/Berlin"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

However, I just realized that this has become somewhat obsolete meanwhile:

In the PowerBI Service switch the **New Look** to ON and then in the title bar next to the report name you get e.g. "Data updated 26/04/20" and in the drop-down menu you can even see the exact update time.

Answer (score 2):

For whatever reason, Microsoft hasn't built in native daylight saving handling yet but please vote for them to fix this [here](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/31072984-allow-formatting-datetimezone-fields-to-user-local).

However, various people have suggested workarounds involving defining the dates/times when DST changes things or referencing an external oracle.

https://intellitect.com/convert-utc-local-time-daylight-savings-support-power-bi/

https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2017/03/28/daylight-saving-time-and-time-zones-in-m/

https://powerpivotpro.com/2019/01/dst-refresh-date-function-power-bi-service/

https://radacad.com/solving-dax-time-zone-issue-in-power-bi

Comment: Thanks for the links and I agree that this all is a "certificate of poverty" for Microsoft, since community-driven Python can handle timezones so very well.